# How to create an ASP.NET CORE with React Quiz App

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, authentication, axios

I'm trying to create a Quiz App in Visual Studio 2022 using ASP.NET Core and React.js template but on my login form I keep seeing an error AxiosError {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …} attached below is my login form code. Thats producing the error in the inspect(console tab)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, Card, CardContent, TextField, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import { Box } from '@mui/system';
import Center from './Center';
import useForm from '../hooks/useForm';
import { ENDPOINTS, createAPIEndpoint } from '../api';
//import { Construction } from '@mui/icons-material';


const getFreshModel = () => ({
    name: '',
    email:'',
})
export default function Login() {
    
    const { 
         values,
        // setValues,
         errors,
         setErrors,
         handldeInputCahange
    } = useForm (getFreshModel);

    const login = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (validate()) {
            createAPIEndpoint(ENDPOINTS.participant)
                .post(values)
                .then(res => console.log(res))
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
        }
    }

    const validate = () => {
        let temp = {}
        temp.email = (/\S+@\S+\.\S+/).test(values.email) ? "" : "Email is not valid"
        temp.name = values.name !== "" ? "" : "This field is required."
        setErrors(temp)
        return Object.values(temp).every(x => x ==="")
    }

    return (
  <Center>

    <Card sx={{width:400}}>
        <CardContent sx={{textAlign:'center'}} >
                    <Typography variant="h3" sx={{ marginY: 3 }}>
                        Driving Test App
            </Typography>
          <Box sx={{
            ' & .MuiTextField-root':{
                margin: 1,
                width: '90%'

            }
            }}>
        <form noValidate autoComplete='on' onSubmit={login}>
            <TextField
                label="Email"
                name="email"
                value={values.email}
                onChange={handldeInputCahange}
                variant="outlined"
                {...(errors.email && { error:true, helperText: errors.email } )}                
                />
            <TextField 
                label="Name" 
                name="name"
                value={values.name}
                onChange={handldeInputCahange}
                variant="outlined"
                {...(errors.name&& { error:true, helperText: errors.name } )}               
                />
                <Button
                    type="submit"
                    variant="contained"
                    size="large"
                    sx={{width:'90'}}>Start</Button>

        </form>     
        </Box>
        </CardContent>
    </Card>
    
  </Center> 
)
}
```

Index.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
```

export const BASE_URL = 'https://localhost:44421/';

export const ENDPOINTS = {
participant: 'participant'
}
export const createAPIEndpoint = endpoint => {

```
let url = BASE_URL + 'api/' + endpoint + '/';
return {
    fetch: () => axios.get(url),
    fetchById: id => axios.get(url + id),
    post: newRecord => axios.post(url, newRecord),
    put: (id, updatedRecord) => axios.put(url + id, updatedRecord),
    delete: id => axios.delete(url + id),
}
```

}

```
  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Driving_Test_Web_App.Models;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Operations;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors;

namespace Driving_Test_Web_App.Controllers
{
   [Route("api/[controller]")]
   [ApiController]
   public class ParticipantController : ControllerBase
   {
       private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

       public ParticipantController(ApplicationDbContext context)
       {
           _context = context;
       }

       // GET: api/Participant
       [HttpGet]
       public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Participant>>> GetParticipants()
       {
         if (_context.Participants == null)
         {
             return NotFound();
         }
           return await _context.Participants.ToListAsync();
       }

       // GET: api/Participant/5
       [HttpGet("{id}")]
       public async Task<ActionResult<Participant>> GetParticipant(int id)
       {
         if (_context.Participants == null)
         {
             return NotFound();
         }
           var participant = await _context.Participants.FindAsync(id);

           if (participant == null)
           {
               return NotFound();
           }

           return participant;
       }

       // PUT: api/Participant/5
       // To protect from overposting attacks, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754
       [HttpPut("{id}")]
       public async Task<IActionResult> PutParticipant(int id, Participant participant)
       {
           if (id != participant.ParticipantId)
           {
               return BadRequest();
           }

           _context.Entry(participant).State = EntityState.Modified;

           try
           {
               await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
           }
           catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
           {
               if (!ParticipantExists(id))
               {
                   return NotFound();
               }
               else
               {
                   throw;
               }
           }

           return NoContent();
       }

       // POST: api/Participant
       // To protect from overposting attacks, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754
       [EnableCors("Policy")]
       [HttpPost]
       public async Task<ActionResult<Participant>> PostParticipant(Participant participant)
       {

           var temp = _context.Participants
               .Where(x => x.Name == participant.Name
               && x.Email == participant.Email)
               .FirstOrDefault();

           if (temp == null)
           {
               _context.Participants.Add(participant);
               await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
           }
           else
               participant = temp;


           return Ok(participant);  
       }

       // DELETE: api/Participant/5
       [HttpDelete("{id}")]
       public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteParticipant(int id)
       {
           if (_context.Participants == null)
           {
               return NotFound();
           }
           var participant = await _context.Participants.FindAsync(id);
           if (participant == null)
           {
               return NotFound();
           }

           _context.Participants.Remove(participant);
           await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

           return NoContent();
       }

       private bool ParticipantExists(int id)
       {
           return (_context.Participants?.Any(e => e.ParticipantId == id)).GetValueOrDefault();
       }
   }
}
```

I have tried to install and enable CORS.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to create a Quiz App in Visual Studio 2022 using ASP.NET
> Core and React.js template but on my login form I keep seeing an error
> AxiosError {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code:
> 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}

In order to inspect this very error you would need to check numerous thing because you haven't shared more details or your network trace details even the error code and reasons of this error might defer based on the error code.

However, the most common reasons are as following:

**Check Network Error Code:**

First of all, if you are getting error code between 5xx or 4xx thats means there might some issue in your cross domain configuration which may includes:

Error in TCP layer or any network issue. Even if your browser prevent loading your js file may also cause network errors.

**CORS Configuration:**

On top of this, when the request aborted outside of axios this might caused from server-side as well. As you said you have installed CORS but not sure, if you have done this in client-side or in your server-side. But even if you install it in your client-side your server-side still need to configure CORS and your controller should aware of your cors policy. You can [check this document for details.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2#cors-with-named-policy-and-middleware-1)

**Note:** Make sure your server is aware of your client-side port and the method you want to allow.

You can do that by defining the request origin like this: `AllowAnyOrigin` to `WithOrigins("Specify the send request origin")`.

```
app.UseCors(policy => policy.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod()
                            .WithOrigins("Define your request origin url from client-side").AllowCredentials());
```

Or you can modify to this `AllowAnyOrigin` to `.SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true)`:

```
app.UseCors(policy => policy.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod()
                            .SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true).AllowCredentials());
```

Note: If that still doesn't work you can try adding `[EnableCors("YourCorsPloicy")]` on top of your controller. In addition, middleware order also matters make sure, the sequence is like this

```
app.UseCors("YourCorsPloicy");
app.UseMvc();
```

**Axios Endpoint or Request URL:**

Another important point is that, make sure, your endpoint has configured either https or http this also significantly caused network error because your base URL translates that your server is in your local machine. Local servers can be accessed using both http and https but if you are sure that you have configured your SSL certificate to access https requests then try checking your CORS policy/ restrictions on the backend. So, double check your CORS policy whether it accepts https or http.

**How to proceed or investigate:**

At the first attempt of investigation, send request from postman, if you could hit your endpoint. If you can hit endpoint, then check your client-side code, because, issue is there, check your endpoint if that has written correct, and check the http verb as well like(POST, PUT defination).

In addition, be aware of your asiox proxy configuration. Although, your error details and code would define more specificly the main cause. Therefore, above steps would help you to figure out how should you proceed.

Comment: The error code is AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404'}

Comment: Oh that's great! Then it means your endpoint url is not correct, well, first checked the url and copy it  to call that from postman if that hits your controller. Make sure your cntroller parameters has been passed accordingly.

Comment: In addition, please include your controller details in order to check the correct url endpoint. After you endpoint I found a `+ '/'` which is not sure how is your controller details. Would be great if you can attach within your question. But yes, your issue is within the descriptions I have answered and that is endpoint or request URL..

Comment: I have attached Participannt controller

Comment: That's fine, have you tried the way I suggested? If you send request from postman can you hit the endpoint or get the response?

Comment: Yes I have tried but it was to no avail.

Comment: What error message are your getting? Could you please share few more details?